# where to download the bootcamp software for windows when updating/installing OSX Lion?

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows

As it says on the cd that after installing the windows insert your OSX disk and run the bootcamp updater that'll install all the drivers and updates to use your mac machine in Windows environment ...

After installing OSX Lion, when I installed Windows 7 on my machine I did as I mentioned above and it deleted the OSX Lion from my machine ... strange behaviour ... and this is because the CD i got was the bootcamp updater for OSX Snow-Leopard ... so this might have cause this strange action ...

when i look for the current release of bootcamp update so on website the most updated release of bootcamp is of early 2011, so if any one tell me where to download the bootcamp software for windows that is compatible with OSX Lion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the MacBook Air / Mac Mini (which can lack a CD/DVD drive as shipped) and Macs running Lion now simply [download their BootCamp drivers](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4407) from within the **Boot Camp Assistant**.

Answer (score 1):

The early 2011 drivers will work. I just went thru installing boot camp on a Mac over the weekend on OS X Lion and that was the download that Lion's Boot Camp Assistant linked to.

Here is Apple's official [Boot Camp on OS X Lion FAQ](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4818) on Apple Support. One of the items on that article takes you to this additional [article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4407) that basically confirms that you should follow the steps on the Boot Camp Assistant (the ones that take you to the early 2011 drivers). Hope this helps.